# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_post_datetime()

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

When I try to open article it shows the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_post_datetime() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\td-cloud-library\state\single\tdb_state_single.php:1666 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\td-cloud-library\wp_templates\tdb_view_single.php(89): tdb_state_single->{closure}() 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\td-cloud-library\wp_templates\tdb_view_single.php(89): Closure->__invoke() 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-includes\template-loader.php(78): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') 
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(17): require('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') 
#5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\td-cloud-library\state\single\tdb_state_single.php on line 1666
```

Anyone know the issue?

Comment: Show the code please.

Comment: $td_article_date_unix = get_post_datetime( $post, 'date', 'gmt' );
            $buffy .= '<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="' . $td_article_date_unix->format( DATE_W3C ) . '">'; thats line 1666

Comment: Welcome to SO John! Please can you clarify what it is that you're trying to do and what you've done so far to solve the problem. Code examples are always useful. For wordpress, please give details of the version you're using and anything custom that you've added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_post_datetime()` was introduced in WordPress version 5.3. You need to update to that version in order to correct the error you are seeing.

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/09/23/date-time-improvements-wp-5-3/

Comment: Thank you  BA_Webimax forgot I removed the update, much appreciated